# PHP AND OR Condition with if else

Tags: php, if-statement, logic

I have a confusion, what is wrong here? if A & B or C is set it should print yes, otherwise it should print the error message

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
$c = null;

if ((is_null($a) && is_null($b)) || is_null($c)) {
    echo 'A and B or C cannot be blank.';
}
else
    echo 'yes';
```

here i have A & B assigned but still its printing 'A and B or C cannot be blank.'

**To Make it more clear.  A= Firstname, B=lastName, C=Email. so user should either give first name and last name otherwise email.**

Comment: The logic is currently: if `$a` AND `$b` is NULL, OR if `$c` is NULL, enter. It's doing what it's suppose to.

Comment: @Epodax but in my acse $a AND $b are set to 1 and 2. they are not null.

Comment: The entire if clause is read/checked, not just the first part.

Comment: i updated the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should do this following way:

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
$c = null;

if ((!is_null($a) && !is_null($b)) || !is_null($c)) {
    echo 'yes';
}
else
{
    echo 'A and B or C cannot be blank.';
}
```

**Update:**

```
if ((is_null($a) || is_null($b)) && is_null($c)) {
    echo 'A and B or C cannot be blank.';
}
```

Comment: its failing when i assigned these. $a = null;
$b = 1;
$c = 3;  i have defined c, so it should say yes but its saying the error.

Comment: can u write this using only if without else. if condition then echo error message. thats all.

Answer (score 2):

You have A&B assigned but the if condition says that A&B or C must be true to print "A and B or C cannot be blank". The A&B part are false at the moment you assigned value to them. This means if( false (A&B assigned) or true (C is not assigned)) which will lead to true and thus print "A and B or C cannot be blank"

Comment: If I were you I would switch what you want to echo. In the if statement echo "yes" and in the else statement echo "A and B or C cannot be blank". Second option is to change all is_null into !is_null and don't switch what is echoed.

Answer (score 2):

```
    $a = 1;
    $b = 2;
    $c = null;

    if ((is_null($a) && is_null($b)) || is_null($c)) {
        echo 'yes';
    }
   else{    
     echo 'A and B or C cannot be blank.';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your original post, you wrote

> if A & B or C is set it should print yes, otherwise it should print the error message

but you are actually testing for unset variables.

A solution closer to your assertion (and also more readable) would be to write the code like this:

```
if (($a && $b) || $c) {
    echo 'yes';
} else {
    echo 'A and B or C cannot be blank.';
}
```

The brackets around `$a && $b` are not necessary, but help determining the expected groupings.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $a = 1;
    $b = 2;
    $c = null;

    if ((empty($a) && empty($b)) || empty($c)) {
         echo 'A and B or C cannot be blank.';
    }
   else{    
      echo 'yes';
    }
```